# Cannot infer generic parameter when defining generic in different module

Tags: swift, generics

I have a swift repository that defines 2 modules:

`Sources/Parser/Parser.swift` contains:

```
public struct Parser<Token, Output> {
  public let parse: (AnyCollection<Token>) throws -> (Output, AnyCollection<Token>)
}

public func countingParser() -> Parser<Character,Int> {
  return Parser { input in
    return ( 1, input.dropFirst( 1 ) )
  }
}
```

`Sources/External/Parser.swift` contains:

```
import Parser

func externalCountingParser() -> Parser<Character,Int> {
  return Parser { input in
    return ( 1, input.dropFirst( 1 ) )
  }
}
```

And for completeness, my `Package.swift` contains:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftBug",
    targets: [ Target( name: "External", dependencies: [ "Parser" ] ) ]
)
```

Despite `countingParser` and `externalCountingParser` being basically the same code, I get a compile error in `External/Parser.swift` with swift 3.0.1.

```
Sources/External/Parser.swift:4:10: error: generic parameter 'Token' could not be inferred
  return Parser { input in
         ^
Parser.Parser:1:15: note: 'Token' declared as parameter to type 'Parser'
public struct Parser<Token, Output> {
              ^
Sources/External/Parser.swift:4:10: note: explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue
  return Parser { input in
         ^
               <Any, Any>
```

No matter what I do to further specify the type of `Parser` inside the function, I cannot get this to compile.  Why does it work fine when defined inside the module that defines `Parser`, but fails to compile when defined outside the same module?

**Edit**: If i make @PEEJWEEJ's edits, as suggested below, there is still a compile error, but the error message has changed:

`Sources/External/Parser.swift`:

```
import Parser

func externalCountingParser() -> Parser<Character,Int> {
  let p: Parser<Character, Int> = Parser<Character,Int>( parse: { input in
    return ( 1, input.dropFirst(1) )
  } )

  return p
}
```

Now produces the error:

```
Sources/External/Parser.swift:4:35: error: expression type 'Parser<Character, Int>' is ambiguous without more context
  let p: Parser<Character, Int> = Parser<Character,Int>( parse: { input in
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

With more type info specified like so in `Sources/External/Parser.swift`:

```
import Parser

func externalCountingParser() -> Parser<Character,Int> {
  let p: Parser<Character, Int> = Parser<Character,Int> { (input: AnyCollection<Character>) -> (Int,AnyCollection<Character>) in
    return ( 1, input.dropFirst(1) )
  }

  return p
}
```

Results in the following diagnostic:

```
Sources/External/Parser.swift:4:96: error: declared closure result '(Int, AnyCollection<Character>)' is incompatible with contextual type '(_, AnyCollection<_>)'
  let p: Parser<Character, Int> = Parser<Character,Int> { (input: AnyCollection<Character>) -> (Int,AnyCollection<Character>) in
                                                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                               (_, AnyCollection<_>)
```

Comment: Have you tried `let parser: Parser<Character,Int> = Parser { *your code* }`? I've seen the type inference sometimes have trouble using the return value of the function to determine the Type

Comment: Also, you should post the method you're using :)

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I updated the question in response to your comment.  The issue isn't that I can't call the method.  I can call `countingParser()` just fine. The issue is that I can't seem to create instances of the `Parser` object from modules that *other than* the Parser module without running into errors. Does that make sense?

Comment: Maybe try putting it in parens? Also the function you're creating doesn't have throw. Not sure how that's dealt with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be the fact that the default constructor for `Parser` is by default **internal**.  Chalk this up to another bad diagnostic message.

If I change the declaration of `struct Parser` to:

```
public struct Parser<Token, Output> {
  public typealias ParseFunction = (AnyCollection<Token>) throws -> (Output, AnyCollection<Token>)
  public let parse: ParseFunction
  public init( parse: @escaping ParseFunction ) {
    self.parse = parse
  }
}
```

Then we compile just fine.